# MD5 checksums with salt

Tags: md5

I thought that when salt is used, MD5 is computed from concatenation string + salt. So the word 'aaa' and salt 'aa' should be the same like 'aaaa' with salt 'a' or 'aaaaa' without salt.

But this is what I got...

```
md5pass aaa aa

$1$aa$EeTKacbSboHIR0fSp2UVf0

md5pass aaaa a

$1$a$M2jh3iKJcBEuJdTGjNcsh0
```

Could you please explain why checksums are different?

Thank you,

Martin

Comment: Please tell us how `md5pass` works

Comment: Doesn't have to be simple concatenation, its implementation specific; e.g. md5(data + salt + salt) would give different results

Comment: Edd, `md5pass` is a linux tool       http://www.examplenow.com/md5pass/man1

Comment: Alex, I tried `md5pass aaaaa a` and `md5pass aaa aa`, results are also different so it seems it is not just md5(data + salt + salt) :-( How can you compare checksums if you don't know the algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

I mixed up two different things - MD5 checksum and password hash

1. MD5 checksum is used for checking that a file was not modified. No salt is used, result is usually a hexadecimal number.
2. MD5 password hash is used to store passwords in non-readable form. It uses MD5(password + salt) in many iterations, result starts with `$1$`.

`md5pass` computes password hash from given passphrase and salt. There are many iterations of md5(pass + salt + result_from_previous_iteration) so not just MD5(pass+salt) as I thought.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29